# How to properly configure the DNS configuration of the VirtualBox to resolve docker containers hostnames within the local network?

Tags: dns, docker, containers, virtualbox, local

## Here is the context

I have three container :

- Container 1 : REST Api
- Container 2 : Web application a.k.a "The Dashboard"
- Container 3 : The database

## My Goal

I want this stack to run on top of Mac OSX or Windows in order to build a coherent application accessible from the local network.

## What I need - DNS Configuration

When the web application is served by the **Container 2** to any client on the local network, the browser need to communicate with the REST API running on the **Container 1**.

I would like to be able to setup within the web application the hostname of the **Container 2** e.g. ***server-api.local***